# Creating view and template for related models in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a problem with listing 'licences' with the view and template with Backbone.
The data structure is like that:

```
    {
        "items":
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Hello Kitty",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "slug": "brand-1",
                "img": "hellokitty",
                "code": "131T003-2",
                "category": "children",
                "licences": "5",
                "licence": [
                    {
                        "_id": "1",
                        "price": "22",
                        "type": "type1",
                        "text": "this is the description of this licence"
                    }, {
                        "_id": "2",
                        "price": "24",
                        "type": "type1",
                        "text": "this is the description of this licence"
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Lana Del Ray",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "slug": "brand-2",
                "img": "lana",
                "code": "p-002",
                "category": "music",
                "licences": "5",
                "licence": [
                    {
                        "_id": "3",
                        "price": "22",
                        "type": "type6",
                         "text": "this is the description of this licence"
                    }, {
                        "_id": "4",
                        "price": "22",
                        "type": "type7",
                         "text": "this is the description of this licence"
                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

I am using licence model and item model, I also created collections for both:

Item Model:

```
define(["backbone", 'models/licenceModel', 'backbone-relational'], function(Backbone, Licence){

    Item = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        relations : [{
            key          : 'licence',
            type         : Backbone.HasMany,
            relatedModel : Licence,
            collectionType: 'licenceCollection'
        }]
        defaults: {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "slug": "",
            "img": "",
            "price": "",
            "code": "",
            "category": "",
            "licences": ""
        }
    });
    return Item;
});
```

Licence model:

```
define(["backbone", 'models/itemModel', 'backbone-relational'], function(Backbone, Item){

    Licence = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            "_id": "",
            "type": "",
            "text": "",
            "price": "",

        }
    });
    return Item;
});
```

Item Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/itemModel'],
    function(Backbone, Item) {

    var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            model: Item
        },
        model: Item,
        url: 'json/items.json',

        initialize: function(){
            this.fetch( { async: false } );
        },

        parse: function(response, xhr) {
            return response.items;
        },

        filterBySlug: function( sl ) {
            return filtered = this.filter(function(data) {
                return data.get('slug') == sl;
            });
        },

        filterByName: function( name ){
            filtered = this.filter(function(data) {
                if(data.get("name").toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1){
                    return data;
                }
            });
            return new ItemCollection(filtered);
        },

        filterById: function(id){
            return this.get(id);
        }
    });

    return ItemCollection;
});
```

Licence Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/licenceModel'],
    function(Backbone, Licence) {

    var LicenceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            model: Licence
        },
        model: Licence,
        url: 'json/items.json',

        initialize: function(){
            this.fetch( { async: false } );
        },

        parse: function(response, xhr) {
            return response.licence;
        }

    });

    return LicenceCollection;
});
```

I got stack with template  and view for listing licences wile desplayind detailView:

```
define(
    ['jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'models/itemModel',
    'text!/templates/detail_template.html'],
    function($, Backbone, _, Item, Template){

    var DetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#todo-list',
        productInfo: $('.product_info'),

        tagName: 'li',
        model: Item,

        events: {
            "click #back": "backToList"
        },

        initialize: function( collection ) {
            this.collection = collection;
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            var compiledTemplate = _.template( Template, this.collection[0].toJSON() );
            container = this.$el;
            this.$el.html( compiledTemplate );
            this.$el.find('li').fadeIn('slow', function(){
                container.find('.info').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        },

        backToList: function(ev){
            //ev.preventDefault();

            $('#clear').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    return DetailView;
});
```

what should i do to list licences in this template:

```
<li id="detail_view" class="row-fluid" data-item="<%- slug %>" data-id="<%- id %>">
    <div class="span6">
        <a href="/" id="back">Back to List</a>
        <img src="/assets/images/<%- img %>.jpg" class="product" />
    </div>
    <div class="info span6">
        <div id="container_info">
            <h2><%- name %></h2>
            <div class="title"><%- description %> </div>
            <div class="code"><strong><%- category %></strong></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: try this to check JSON? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Valid JSON, the problem is  i don't know hot I can gab this data and put it in html with backbone

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed it, but are you actually creating an instance of the View anywhere?

You've defined one and put the render call in the initialise, but you then need to create it to kick things off, either explicitly or via a Router and a history.start() call...

The other part I'm not sure about is your template usage - I'm not familiar with Underscore usage, but would expect that you compile the template once with the _.template call without any data, then call the result of that with the data to obtain the html as [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render).